# Formal definition of a language accepted by PDA

Tags: pushdown-automata, stacks

I am a bit confused on how to give a formal definition of the language accepted by A? [image: PDA]

I can describe it by "The language of all strings starting with n-many a's or n-many c's followed by n-many b's" and I have tried to give a formal definition by:

L(A) = {a^n c^n b^n | n ∈ N}

Is that the correct way to define it?

Comment: The language $\{a^nc^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not context-free, so this can't be it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's $L(A)=\{a^n c^m b^{2n}| n,m \in \mathbb{N}, m \geq 2\}$

For every a push 2 zeros on the stack, so it's for now just called a^n. 
The number of c's is m, because it is not related to the number of a's. You can accept any number of c's (larger than 2) no matter how many a's were there.
The number of b's is twice the number of a's because you accept for every 0 on the stack 1 b, but wrote twice 0 for every a on the stack.

In fact the language $L(A)=\{a^n c^n b^n| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ can't be accepted by any PDA, but only a linear bounded automate(LBA) or a Turingmachine (or other similar models) The reasoning is that if you count the number of a's and want to have the same number of c's and b's later(not mixed) your stack will be empty after you sucessfully counted all the c's and the PDA will have forgotten the number to check whether the b's appear in this number.

Comment: The number of c's is greater than or equal to 2.

Comment: @JimHefferon Thank you. I missed that first. I edited it now

Comment: Oh, thank you both very very much